Australian 240V cord came to the U.S
I bought an espresso maker off eBay. It came from Australia. Dummy me didn’t check to see if it was compatible. It has a 20amp 240v cord (Australian/China/New Zealand style male).
What can I do to make it work in the U.S.? I have a 50amp outlet that my other espresso maker plugged into.
Can I rewire the machines cord?
Am I screwed?
Be nice. I’m new to all of this.
Thank you.

What is it actually rated for (should be on a label on the machine). Perhaps 20A 208V works, perhaps not.

Does it have an actual AU/NZ approval, or just a CE mark?

Can you re-wire? - maybe. What does the manufacturer say?

If this machine cost thousands of dollars you can easily get an electrician to install the necessary outlet and plug.   If it cost much less than a thousand, you're better off tossing it and going to Walmart for a new one.

If possible to re-plug for our 240(two hots/no neutral) then you will want to drop that 50 amp circuit down to 20 amp for safety.  The receptacle and the breaker.  Can keep the bigger wires, maybe pigtail to 12 gauge at the receptacle and breaker.

Data nameplate on the equipment? How many amps or watts?

If you hook that up to a typical US home 15A 120V outlet, then no matter what you do it's going to get less than half the power it was designed for, which will make boiling water slow if it happens at all. Even with a transformer, you just can't get more power than the circuit is intended to carry.
If you have a 240V outlet -- maybe an outlet for an air conditioner or clothes dryer or electric stove  which ran at that voltage -- you may get able to fit this machine with a suitable plug and have it work. But check with the manufacturer that it will be happy running at 60 cycles per second (60 Hertz); it's possible that it won't be.
Personally I'd say find someone who is travelling to a 240V country and give it to them as a departure gift, or put it back on eBay and hope to get some of your money back.
